# Error in raspberry Pi for passengers counting

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I am using this python program in raspberry pi 4 for passengers counting.This program works very well in my laptop as the camera opens and also the counting of people is done but it is not working in raspberry pi 4.
I am using Raspberry pi  4 and 7" display for this project.I think it is not taking any frame input as i tried to print frame and it printed none.The camera is even not starting. Thankyou For the help.

It is showing following Error:

```
Unable to stop the stream: Invalid argument
False
None
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0) in locateROI, file /build/opencv-L65chJ/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 949
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/tracking.py", line 31, in <module>
    fgmask = cv2.blur(frame, (10,10))
cv2.error: /build/opencv-L65chJ/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:949: error: (-215) dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0 in function locateROI
```

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
fgbg = cv2.bgsegm.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG(history=150, backgroundRatio=0.3)

def line1(x,y):
    return y - (29*x)/96.0 - 300

def line2(x,y):
    return y - (29*x)/96.0 - 500


crossedAbove = 0
crossedBelow = 0
points = set()
pointFromAbove = set()
pointFromBelow = set()

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('pedestrianOutput.avi',fourcc, 25.0, (1920,1080))
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
while(1):
    pointInMiddle = set()
    prev = points
    points = set()
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print(ret)
    print(frame)
    fgmask = frame
    fgmask = cv2.blur(frame, (10,10))
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(fgmask)
    fgmask = cv2.medianBlur(fgmask, 7)
    oldFgmask = fgmask.copy()
    contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fgmask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,1)
    for contour in contours:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
        if w>40 and h>90:
            cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
            point = (int(x+w/2.0), int(y+h/2.0))
            points.add(point)
    for point in points:
        (xnew, ynew) = point
        if line1(xnew, ynew) > 0 and line2(xnew, ynew) < 0:
            pointInMiddle.add(point)
        for prevPoint in prev:
            (xold, yold) = prevPoint
            dist = cv2.sqrt((xnew-xold)*(xnew-xold)+(ynew-yold)*(ynew-yold))
            if dist[0] <= 120:
                if line1(xnew, ynew) >= 0 and line2(xnew, ynew) <= 0:
                    if line1(xold, yold) < 0: # Point entered from line above
                        pointFromAbove.add(point)
                    elif line2(xold, yold) > 0: # Point entered from line below
                        pointFromBelow.add(point)
                    else:   # Point was inside the block
                        if prevPoint in pointFromBelow:
                            pointFromBelow.remove(prevPoint)
                            pointFromBelow.add(point)

                        elif prevPoint in pointFromAbove:
                            pointFromAbove.remove(prevPoint)
                            pointFromAbove.add(point)

                if line1(xnew, ynew) < 0 and prevPoint in pointFromBelow: # Point is above the line
                    print('One Crossed Above')
                    print(point)
                    crossedAbove += 1
                    pointFromBelow.remove(prevPoint)

                if line2(xnew, ynew) > 0 and prevPoint in pointFromAbove: # Point is below the line
                    print('One Crossed Below')
                    print(point)
                    crossedBelow += 1
                    pointFromAbove.remove(prevPoint)


    for point in points:
        if point in pointFromBelow:
            cv2.circle(frame, point, 3, (255,0,255),6)
        elif point in pointFromAbove:
            cv2.circle(frame, point, 3, (0,255,255),6)
        else:
            cv2.circle(frame, point, 3, (0,0,255),6)
    cv2.line(frame, (0,300), (1920,880), (255, 0, 0), 4)
    cv2.line(frame, (0,500), (1920,1080), (255, 0, 0), 4)
    cv2.putText(frame,'People Going Above = '+str(crossedAbove),(1200,50), font, 1,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.putText(frame,'People Going Below = '+str(crossedBelow),(1200,100), font, 1,(255,255,255),2,cv2.LINE_AA)
    cv2.imshow('a',oldFgmask)
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    out.write(frame)
    l = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xff
    if l == 27:
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

`cap.read()` return `False` and an empty `frame`.
Then you try to apply blur on that `frame` which trigger an exception.
You should process the frame only if is not empty.
There could be several reason to get an empty frame :

- device 1 is not available (but I think OpenCV will post an error message in that case)
- device is not yet ready for sending frame, because it has just been opened and still initializing
- device has no frame to return, in this case you should wait a little for a frame to be available and try again

I'll start with the later and put everything after `cap.read()` under an `if ret:` statement.

```
    while(1):
    pointInMiddle = set()
    prev = points
    points = set()
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    print(ret)
    print(frame)
    if ret:
        fgmask = frame
        fgmask = cv2.blur(frame, (10,10))
        fgmask = fgbg.apply(fgmask)
        fgmask = cv2.medianBlur(fgmask, 7)
        oldFgmask = fgmask.copy()
        contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(fgmask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,1)
        ...
```

Comment: sorry I though I was clear enough, I'm editing the answer with a code snippet